# Shopper theme custom javascript var

Tags: extensions, theme, javascript

In Shopper theme, there's a custom variable in skin\frontend\shopper\default\js\script.js file of the theme, it's not instantiated in this file, however it's called:

```
if (Shopper.totop) {
    $().UItoTop({scrollSpeed:400});
}
```

I made some modifications in the theme and now i'm getting this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Shopper is not defined
```

I can see in template/page/html/head.phtml that the variable is instantiated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var Shopper = {};
    Shopper.price_circle = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('shoppersettings/design/price_circle') ?>;
    Shopper.fixed_header = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('shoppersettings/design/fixed_header') ?>;
    Shopper.totop = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('shoppersettings/ajax/totop') ?>;
    Shopper.responsive = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('shoppersettings/design/responsive') ?>;
.
.
.
.
</script>
```

Where's the problem then?, can anyone give a hint?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that after modifications you're loading them in wrong order, including script.js BEFORE you declare Shopper variable?

Comment: nope, i'm loading script.js at the end of the head reference in local.xml file:

Comment: Any chance I can see the result myself? I'm pretty sure there's something simple, like wrong capitalization, or problem with scope (such as defining Shopper INSIDE another function).

Answer (score 1):

Also it will make sense to execute your custom code on page load.

For prototype:

```
Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function() {
    ...
});
```

For jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```